# What are ATS in Betjeman's Henley-upon-Thames poem (beefy ATS without their hats)

Tags: meaning

From [the Betjeman poem 'Henley-upon-Thames'](https://experiencehenley.co.uk/henley-on-thames-john-betjeman/):

> When(*) shall I see the Thames again?
> The prow-promoted gems again,
> As beefy ATS
> Without their hats
> Come shooting through the bridge?

(*) sometimes quoted as "Oh shall I see..."

It was written during (or around the time of) WWII, for context.

Comment: Is that a limerick? 'ATS' looks like initials...then it would be pronounced to rhyme with 'hats'.

Comment: Not a limerick: but yes, Wikipedia does say it was often pronounced as an acronym. Like Wrens and Wracs, I guess.

Comment: Sounds like they are rowing on the Thames.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely the [Auxiliary Territorial Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_Territorial_Service), which was the women's branch of the British Army during WWII.

Comment: Wikipedia even has photos of the hats.

Comment: That would be 'ats on ATS then @StuartF!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark 'At's it.

Comment: I agree, but I've never heard ATS pronounced as anything but the initials A T S. Betjeman, being contemporary with the WWII military, would know better than me but perhaps he was just joking. Also ATS was the name of the service not a plural noun for the members of the ATS, I've only heard members of my parents generation talk about "ATS girls".